# RadioButton change event jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I write this event for RadioButton change event.but for first timer that page load.it doesnt work.why?

```
//html mvc code
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DigitalFile, false) خیر
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DigitalFile, true) بله

     <script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='DigitalFile']").change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() == "True") {
            $("#MapZoning").attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#MapZoning").attr("disabled", true);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in document ready handler?

Comment: yes it works after i change selected radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your question.
**.but for first timer that page load.it doesnt work.why?**
If you are saying that when the page loads, the attribute of mapZoning doesn't change, then that's because you are only calling the function when some change occurs in your DigitalFile (i.e., someone, checks it or unchecks it)

Comment: yes i want in page load also this become set.how can i do that?

Comment: call the function in $(document).ready(**your function here**);
Don't remove the function from .change or else change won't work

Comment: how to check if $this is checked or not?

Comment: i add general if($this.is(':checked')) and solved the problem